# How can i make the F11 act as ctrl+double click with autohotkey?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

i want the F11 key in my keyboard to act as ctrl+double click in windows in any program,i've installed AutoHotKey but i've zero knowledge on it,thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try

`F11::
Send, ^{Click 2}
return`